# How to write jquery to find html element id attribute value and set that value to same html class attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

currently trying to  write jquery to find html element "area" and get id attribute value and set that value to same html element class attribute?

```
<map name="map">
<area id="test" />
.
.
.
//100 area tag
</map>
```

Comment: But why .......... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
el = $(body).find("area");
$.each(el, function(key, element) {
    element.addClass(element.attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the each lookup and go through all area tags. Inside the callback you can refer to the current area by using `$(this)`.

```
$("area").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).attr("id"));
});
```